# My brand new car is shaking while steering wheel is not

Tags: tires, wheels, dodge, ram

I have bought a brand new Dodge Ram 1500 2015 model. The car is shaking at low speed 80km/hr (50 mph) while the steering wheel is not shaking. I can feel the vibration in the seats, however the vibration stops at higher speed 100km/h (60 mph ) or higher. The dealer says that its a problem in balancing and he can change the tires also and re-balance.

Can it be any other problem?

Please advise as I know if its a tire problem it should increase while acceleration not fading?

Comment: You feel NO vibration in the steering wheel?

Comment: Yes, i dont feel vibration in the steering wheel.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to continue vibrating. It can get to a point where the vibrations stop for a period of time, then start again at higher speeds. I would bet you just haven't gotten to the speed where it starts again (not that I'm suggesting you try to go that speed). It's just like at lower speeds you don't feel a wobble, because it hasn't gotten to the point where it occurs. It happens in cycles.

Let the dealership fix the issue and be done with it.

Comment: I got what u mean. So your opinion that its a balance and tires issue .. right ?

Comment: I believe it is a *wheel/tire balance issue*. If the dealership is willing to replace the tires as part of the balance process, then let them. Even if they don't replace the tires, they should at least be re-balancing the ones which are on there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider an engineering perspective behind it. A condition called as fretting or brinnelling is a state when new brand vehicles kept in warehouse for a long time ( 5 months to 1 year ) & the wheel bearings develop a stage called as fretting due to one point load in the bearing while vehicle is completely static for a long time. so when vehicles goes for delivery to customers & when they first drive at speed above 80 or 100 kmph, mild to severe vibration occurs & one of clear symptoms is passenger seat vibration .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sounds like a wheel balancing problem. The reason you might not feel it is that pick up trucks have what is a called a dead center in the steering. The dead center is a point where steering the wheel does not steer the tires. Let the dealer fix it.

Comment: I got what you mean. That is what makes me dont feel this vibration in steering wheel. Your opinion that it is a balance and tires issue ?

Comment: @H.sayed Yes, have the dealer balance the tires. It could be a rare case of a bad tire, too. Having them look into it is the best option since it is covered by warranty. Best of luck!